# Most widely used software for complex-system researchers

Tags: nonlinear-system

Now I started to learn the basics regarding analysis of complex systems theory. I am especially concerning about studying non-linear dynamic systems and trying to simulate some examples denoted on my textbook.

I had several options - such as mathematica, matlab or python modules, etc.

I'd like to know which one is the most widely used option for the group of people who's seriously participating in this field.

Any recommendations would be grateful.

Comment: I think that matlab, python or julia are good candidates.

Answer (score 1):

I am an electrical engineering student and automatics is my field and as far as I know pplane8 is the best free software (works with matlab) for simulating the behavior and the dynamics of every system :) All you have to do is find the state-space model of the system.